# How to use python functions from a separate file without prefix on replit

Tags: python, import, python-module

In replit I have put my functions required to run my code in a separate file than the code itself, I have figured out how to import the code but would like to call the functions without the function prefix shown below.

```
import scienceFunctions
print(scienceFunctions.findElement(13))
print(scienceFunctions.findElementSymbol(15))
```

This is how I want to be able to call the functions

```
import scienceFunctions
print(findElement(13))
print(findElementSymbol(15))
```

Comment: ```from scienceFunctions import *```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Hi, as patrick says, you can do it with `from scienceFunctions import *` But I would recomend a more explicit importing with: `from scienceFunctions import findElement, findElementSymbol`. This way it's more clear from where the function came... Also you can rename the module with a more short name in the import, this way you will not have problem overwriting functions from different sources if you extend your program. Something like `import scienceFunction as sf` and then calling `sf.findElement` (that's not what you're looking for but I think it's the best way to import from other modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from scienceFunctions import findElement, findElementSymbol
# or: from scienceFunctions import *


print(findElement(13))
print(findElementSymbol(15))
```